# VB.Net get text after keypress

Tags: vb.net

I am running some custom validations on textbox keypress event.

When a user presses a key I want to find out the text that would exist after that particular key press.

Eg. If the textbox currently contains 12.4 and the user press "6" key I want to find out what the text would be afterwards. I tried appending the `e.KeyChar` to the end of the textbox.text but there would be problems if the user highlights portions of the textbox and then press a key.

Is there anyway to detect the actual value that would exist after a key has been pressed?

Comment: what about the `.TextChanged` event? instead of trying to foretell the future, evaluate what it actually is.  Or just allow the TB to be a user sandbox until they press OK/Send/Submit/Done...  Trying to validate each keypress is rarely worth the effort

Comment: I can't use the textchanged event. This is for a amount field & if the user accidentally press a alphabetical key I want it to be ignored. There are some other validations as well..

Comment: ...then use a numericupdown control or a maskededit control

Comment: This textbox is hosted on a datagridview and I tried hosting a numeric up down but ran into some issues, I can't remember what exactly was the issue. But textbox gives me the flexibility to do anything & that's why I used it..

Comment: GoTo 1: use the TextChanged event and if you dont like the new contents, roll it back.  I think this will also catch Ctrl-V which keypress wont

Answer (score 1):

You would have to disassemble the current text based on the current caret position, examine the incoming text, and then reassemble the text again:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                                                Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
  Dim part1 As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.SelectionStart)
  Dim part2 As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.SelectionStart + _
                                                TextBox1.SelectionLength)
  Dim character As String = String.Empty
  If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
    character = e.KeyChar.ToString
    Dim result As String = part1 & character & part2
    'Do something with result...
  Else
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```